# reverseProxy: how to change content in embedded JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, apache, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

I use Apache HTTP 2.4 as a reverse proxy. My configuration works fine except one thing:

- I would like to change a string content (url) in an embedded JavaScript file

This is my actual virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost web.mydomain.com:80>
      ServerName web.mydomain.com
      ServerAlias web.mydomain.com

      DocumentRoot "..."
      ...

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
      
      #Options -Indexes
      #ProxyRequests On
      #ProxyPreserveHost Off

      # Web App
      ProxyPass /hello http://middleware.mydomain.com:8082/hello-world-0.0.7
      ProxyPassReverse /hello http://middleware.mydomain.com:8082/hello-world-0.0.7
      
      AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
      Substitute "s|hello-world-0.0.7|hello|ni" 
</VirtualHost>
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you should be able to configure the external URL in your application server, thereby eliminating the need to do the substitution in your Apache server. Such a configuration would be more efficient.

Did you validate in your browser that the returned Content-Type matches your filter? You indicate a Javascript file but filter for text/html. (e.g. Chrome: open Developer tools > navigate to the page > open Network tab > click on the resource that needs substitution > Look for the Content-Type header in the response headers). The Content-Type header should match your filter.

If it still does not work, it is likely that the application server returns gzipped content (check for Content-Encoding: gzip in the response headers). In that case, it makes sense that substitution won't work.

To work around that, add the following directive in your Apache configuration:

```
RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
```

Please note that this results in a performance penalty since more data needs to be sent across the network. I won't recommend this solution in a production environment since it applies to all requests for the current Virtual Host. If you only need to use substitution for a single file, I recommend wrapping the AddOutputFilterByType, Substitute and RequestHeader directives in a  block, so that Apache only does the additional work for that file:

```
<Location "/hello/path/to/your/javascript/file.js">
  RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
  Substitute "s|hello-world-0.0.7|hello|ni" 
</Location>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the solution and for the useful comments. The reason why  the content type in my rule is text/html is because it is used for changing the content in html.head.base tag. I added the suggested configuration to my virtual host definition and it works like a charm. Thx!

Comment: Can I have one more question? My rules above works if the url is http://web.mydomain.com/hello/. In that case the html.head.base tag has changed as I expected. But if the request url is http://web.mydomain.com/hello/whatever then the html.head.base tag contains the original content. It is not changed. Why?

Comment: What did you exactly put into your configuration? The Location-directive limits the scope of the configuration directives that it contains to URLs that start with the path after Location. So, if the second URL is different, it would make sense. If it isn't, I'm not sure what is going on.

Removing the Location directive should resolve the problem, but the reason I recommend it is to minimise the performance penalty I mentioned in my original answer.

Comment: Here I we were talking about two different thinks. The configuration bellow # Web App comment in my original post changes the content of the  html.head.base tag. It works fine if the url is  web.mydomain.com/hello but if the request url is web.mydomain.com/hello/whatever then the html.head.base tag contains the original content (hello-world-0.0.7 instread of hello).